# Pandas eval: Run method on generated result (e.g. (A/B).min())

Tags: pandas

I am looking to run a pandas method (e.g. `.min()`) inside eval on the result of an eval operation (e.g. `A/B`).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.util.testing.getTimeSeriesData())
df.eval('(A/B).min()', engine='python')
```

The above code fails with

```
AttributeError: 'Div' object has no attribute 'value'
```

The operation could of course be done in two separate evals but I would like to keep everything in one string for code readability.

Any ideas?

Comment: try `df.eval('(A/B)', engine='python').min()`

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I would like to have the full evaluation inside the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df.eval('A.div(B).min()', engine='python')
```

This function `.div(...)` returns `pd.Series`, and hence `.min()` can be used

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware that the return value of  `.div` is different from the `/` operator.